# heat kernel on n-sphere

Tags: partial-differential-equations, smooth-manifolds, heat-equation

I'm interested in diffusion, a.k.a. the heat kernel driven by the Laplace-Beltrami operator, on the $n$-dimensional sphere.  There are lots of bounds showing that, for small times, it behaves in a way close to the heat kernel in $\mathbb{R}^n$: that is, the probability $p_t(\theta)$ that we have moved an angle $\theta$ away from the starting point, at time $t$, is bounded by a Gaussian of variance $t$.  But I need some control on how the errors or leading constants in these bounds depend on $n$.

The most precise estimates I've found (where the sphere has radius $1$) are 
$$
p_t(\theta) \sim \frac{\mathrm{e}^{-\theta^2/2t}}{(2\pi t)^{n/2}} \left( \frac{\theta}{\sin \theta} \right)^{(n-1)/2}
$$
This is the first term of an asymptotic series, and if I understand a paper by Molchanov correctly, for fixed $n$ the next term would give a multiplicative error of $1+O(t)$.  But does the constant hidden in $O(t)$ grow rapidly with $n$?

Another family of bounds gives
$$
p_t(\theta) \le C \,t^{-n/2} \,\mathrm{e}^{-\theta^2/(4+\delta)t}
$$
Any constant value of $\delta$ would be fine with me.  But we need $C$ to decay roughly as $(4\pi)^{-n/2}$ to match the normalization of the flat-space Gaussian.

UPDATE: it turns out all we really need for our application is the following.  If we think of the heat kernel as a stochastic process, let $\theta$ be the angular distance from the initial point.  We know that for small enough $t$ we have 
$$
\mathbb{E}(\theta) \le C' \sqrt{nt}
$$
for some constant $C'$, as it would be in flat space; but we need to know this holds for all $t$ up to $1/n$ or so.  In other words, we need to know that the error term doesn't do something horrible like
$$
\mathbb{E}(\theta) = C' \sqrt{nt} + O(2^n t) \, . 
$$
This would follow, for instance, from a bound on the error term in Molchanov's estimate above, although this might be overkill.

Thanks!

Cris

Comment: FYI: If you're not getting a helpful response here regarding technical mathematics, consider asking it over at MathOverflow as well.

Comment: Now posted on [MathOverflow](http://mathoverflow.net/q/176698). Crossposting in such a case is fine, but you should include links between questions in both ways (e.g., in a comment such as this one).